# How to live stream Raw H264 Encoded Data on IOS from server

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, video, live-streaming

I am working on Client Server application.

**My scenario is that:**

Computer is my server and camera is attached with it. Server get raw `h264` compressed video stream from camera and uses `TCP/IP protocol (sockets)` to send this compressed video stream to client side which is `iPhone` in my case over the `WIFI`.

**I have to targets:**

- to Record that stream on `iPhone`.
- to live stream that stream on `iPhone`.

I completed my first part in which server get stream from camera and send it to client over `WIFI`. The client receive the data in raw H264 Compressed form. Apply MP4 MUX and stores it on `iPhone` in `.mp4` format. This is done and running fine

Now i am stuck in my second requirement.

How to live stream that incoming raw `h264` compressed data on iPhone ?

Answer (score 0):

iOS can not play a raw h.264 stream. It must be streamed as HLS.

Comment: Actually i am avoiding Apple `HLS` protocol as i build my entire application on `TCP/IP` methodology and almost half of my work is done. Now i am thinking of another solution for `live streaming`, When user press live streaming button on `client` side first i will record fixed duration (5 to 10 second) file in `mp4` format and then fill that in to buffer (Buffer can hold up to 5 to 10 that fixed size files) and from buffer read that file one by one and apply some functionality which read `mp4` file from buffer convert it in to `.ts` & `.m3u8` File and send it to `MPmovieplayer` for playing.

Comment: This will add a delay in live streaming but it will not be a problem for me right now. kindly can any body tell me how to achieve that functionality to convert this `.mp4` file in to `.ts` & `.m3u8` file on the go (during the code execution).

Comment: I don't think apple will approve an app that streams in this fashion. This a a lot of development work to take a gamble on. You can use libavformat to do the conversion. But this code is GPL. Other that than you can write a mp4 parser + AVCC to anneb-b (with repeated sps/pps) converter, and a TS muxer.